# "opencv_core220.dll is missing"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012

When connect Visual Studio with openCV there is an error message "opencv_core220.dll is missing".

How can I find this file?

What is its location?

Why this message was generated?

What wrong steps that I made during connecting openCV and VS?

Comment: Which opencv version did you install?

Answer (score 2):

It should be under path

> *OpenCV-Path* **`\build\x64`** *or* **`x86\vc10`** *or*  **`vc11\bin`**

p.s.: Use `x64` if you compile your project under `x64`, and `x86` for `Win32`. Use `vc10` for VS2010 and `vc11` for VS2012.

---

To make it work, you should do ***one*** of the following steps:

1. Add this path to `Path` environment variable.
2. Add this path to your project's `Debugging Environment`.
3. Copy `opencv_core220.dll` to the output folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

So, the paths were already described above by *herohuyongtao*

For more that it's an old situation when adding opencv in VS, it's still occurs.

I got the same problem when trying OpenCV 3.4.5 / VS2017 and ***another way*** to get it solved when the usual paths just don't is to go to:

**LINKER** -> **INPUT** -> ***DelayLoadDlls*** and insert the specified DLL there.

[Using Delay DLL to solve missing DLL problems (opencv) | post by TIJOLO Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsoJd.png)